# OracleJET: How to change grunt release directory

Tags: gruntjs, oracle-jet

I created an javascript app using Oracle JET v2.0. Running

```
grunt build:release
```

creates **release** folder in the project root folder. How to change this to point to another path, for example outside project root?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Yeoman generator, you can follow the Grunt flow in `scripts/grunt/tasks/build.js`. You'll see under `if (target === "release")`
 that it runs a number of tasks in order.

Unfortunately the **release** folder name is hardcoded in many of those tasks' config files. So it might make more sense to add a task at the end of your build:release task to copy the built release into a new directory.  You could add a target to the `scripts/grunt/config/copy.js` file named myFinalRelease:

```
module.exports = {
  release: 
  {
    src: [
      "**",
      "!bower_components/**",
      "!grunt/**",
      "!scripts/**",
      "!js/**/*.js",
      "js/libs/**",
      "!js/libs/**/*debug*",
      "!js/libs/**/*debug*/**",
      "!node_modules/**",
      "!release/**",
      "!test/**",
      "!.gitignore",
      "!bower.json",
      "!Gruntfile.js",
      "!npm-shrinkwrap.json",
      "!oraclejetconfig.json",
      "!package.json"
    ],
    dest: "release/",
    expand: true
  },
   myFinalRelease: 
  {
    cwd: 'release/',
    src: ['**'],
    dest: "myRelease",
    expand: true
  }

};
```

Then add that task:target as a copy step on the last line of the release section of `scripts/grunt/tasks/build.js`:

```
...
if (target === "release")
   {
     grunt.task.run(
     [
       "clean:release",
       "injector:mainReleasePaths",   
       "uglify:release",
       "copy:release",          
       "requirejs",
       "clean:mainTemp",
       "copy:myFinalRelease"
     ]);
   }
...
```

To make this more robust, you should do some additional cleanup tasks if you're doing a lot of build:release'ing, because the myRelease folder won't get cleaned out unless you create tasks to do it.  Or you might look into other Grunt plugins like grunt-contrib-rename.

If this is too much copying and too messy for your tastes, you could instead edit all of the hardcoded task configs to change the name of the **release** directory.  You'll find the directory name shows up in these four files:

**`scripts/grunt/config/clean.js`**

```
...
release: ["release/*"],
...
```

**`scripts/grunt/config/uglify.js`**

```
...
dest:"release/js"
...
```

**`scripts/grunt/config/copy.js`**

```
...
dest: "release/",
...
```

**`scripts/grunt/config/require.js`**

```
...
  baseUrl: "./release/js",
  name: "main-temp",
  mainConfigFile: "release/js/main-temp.js",
  optimize: "none",
  out: "release/js/main.js"...
...
```